# Is gradle necessary for android wear?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I have a project that is not currently using gradle. I am having trouble migrating it to gradle. Is there a way to use android wear without using gradle?

Comment: You may wish to consider asking some Stack Overflow questions to get help with your Gradle-related issues.

Comment: I just don't know where to begin, so many issues migrating

Comment: how come that you are not using/not need gradle in the first place?

Comment: The project I forked did not use gradle

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Gradle makes wearable development much easier but there are some unoffical Eclipse resources for Wearable

https://github.com/emezias/WearEclipse

https://github.com/j796160836/DemoWearApp